# Save multiply states into one flow

Tags: corda

I have to execute transaction "or roll it back" with several states.
For instance:
1. Create and save state A.
2. Update state B.
3. Create and save state C.
At the moment I do it with subFlow execution for the each of the state. But theoretically, subFlow for step 2 can be crashed. In this case step 1 and step 3 will be stored but step 2 will be missed. Do you have the best practice pattern or example how to do it with Corda?

Answer (score 0):

Flows in Corda are checkpointed. If a node crashes, it replays the flow actions since the last checkpoint. It is therefore not possible for step 2 to be "missed".

Comment: Looks very cool, do you have this detailed explanation itno white paper ?

Comment: Yep, see page 11 of https://docs.corda.net/_static/corda-technical-whitepaper.pdf.